# TFBertForSequenceClassification for multi label classification

Tags: tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to fine-tune a bert model for multi-label classification.

here is how my data looks like. I have put the entire code [on this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QT2uEp8LtFyKjBixszasRwU8ZYg159r5?usp=sharing)

```
({'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([    2,  8318,  1379,  7892,  2791, 20630,     1,     4,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0], dtype=int32)>, 
'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>}, 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(7,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])>)
```

The first element is the id,
The second element corresponds to the attention_masks
the third one are the labels - here I have 7 lables.

**First effort:**

```
        MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH = 'HooshvareLab/bert-fa-base-uncased'
        NUM_LABELS = 7
        
        from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification, BertConfig
        model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
            MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH, 
            config=BertConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH, num_labels=NUM_LABELS, problem_type="multi_label_classification")
            )
        
        loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
        history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=115, validation_data=valid_dataset, validation_steps=7)
```

```
which ends up with the following error
```

```
    InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    
    <ipython-input-48-4408a1f17fbe> in <module>()
         10 loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
         11 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
    ---> 12 history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=115, validation_data=valid_dataset, validation_steps=7)
         13 
         14 
    
    1 frames
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
         53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
         54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
    ---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
         56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
         57     if name is not None:
    
    InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
    
    Detected at node 'Equal' defined at (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
          "__main__", mod_spec)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
          app.launch_new_instance()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
          app.start()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
          self.io_loop.start()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
          self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
          self._run_once()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
          handle._run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
          self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
          handler_func(fileobj, events)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
          return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
          self._handle_recv()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
          self._run_callback(callback, msg)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
          callback(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
          return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
          return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
          handler(stream, idents, msg)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
          user_expressions, allow_stdin)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
          res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
          return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
          interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
          if self.run_code(code, result):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
          exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
        File "<ipython-input-48-4408a1f17fbe>", line 12, in <module>
          history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=115, validation_data=valid_dataset, validation_steps=7)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
          return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
          tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
          return step_function(self, iterator)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
          outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
          outputs = model.train_step(data)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1156, in train_step
          self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 459, in update_state
          metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
          update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 178, in update_state_fn
          return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 729, in update_state
          matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 4086, in sparse_categorical_accuracy
          return tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())
    Node: 'Equal'
    required broadcastable shapes
         [[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_187978]
```

**Second Effort** inspired by [this piece of code](https://github.com/NZbryan/NLP_bert/blob/master/tf2.0_bert_emb_en_MultiLabel.py#L61)

```
    from transformers import TFBertPreTrainedModel
    from transformers import TFBertMainLayer
    
    
    class TFBertForMultilabelClassification(TFBertPreTrainedModel):
    
        def __init__(self, config, *inputs, **kwargs):
            super(TFBertForMultilabelClassification, self).__init__(config, *inputs, **kwargs)
            self.num_labels = config.num_labels
    
            self.bert = TFBertMainLayer(config, name='bert')
            self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)
            self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(config.num_labels,
                                                    kernel_initializer='random_normal', #get_initializer(config.initializer_range),
                                                    name='classifier',
                                                    activation='sigmoid')
    
        def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
            outputs = self.bert(inputs, **kwargs)
    
            pooled_output = outputs[1]
    
            pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output, training=kwargs.get('training', False))
            logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)
    
            outputs = (logits,) + outputs[2:]  # add hidden states and attention if they are here
    
            return outputs  # logits, (hidden_states), (attentions)
    
    
    MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH = 'HooshvareLab/bert-fa-base-uncased'
    NUM_LABELS = len(y_train[0])
    
    model = TFBertForMultilabelClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH, num_labels=NUM_LABELS)
    
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001,epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1)
    # we do not have one-hot vectors, we can use sparce categorical cross entropy and accuracy
    loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
    metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, validation_data=valid_dataset)
```

returns the following error

```
    InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    
    <ipython-input-49-8aa1173bef76> in <module>()
          4 metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
          5 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
    ----> 6 history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, validation_data=valid_dataset)
    
    1 frames
    
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
             53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
             54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
        ---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
             56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
             57     if name is not None:
        
        InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
        
        Detected at node 'Equal' defined at (most recent call last):
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
              "__main__", mod_spec)
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
              exec(code, run_globals)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
              app.launch_new_instance()
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
              app.start()
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
              self.io_loop.start()
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
              self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
              self._run_once()
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
              handle._run()
            File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
              self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
              handler_func(fileobj, events)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
              return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
              self._handle_recv()
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
              self._run_callback(callback, msg)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
              callback(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
              return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
              return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
              handler(stream, idents, msg)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
              user_expressions, allow_stdin)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
              res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
              return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
              interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
              if self.run_code(code, result):
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
              exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
            File "<ipython-input-49-8aa1173bef76>", line 6, in <module>
              history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, validation_data=valid_dataset)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
              return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
              tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
              return step_function(self, iterator)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
              outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
              outputs = model.train_step(data)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1156, in train_step
              self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 459, in update_state
              metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
              update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 178, in update_state_fn
              return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 729, in update_state
              matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 4086, in sparse_categorical_accuracy
              return tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())
        Node: 'Equal'
        required broadcastable shapes
             [[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_214932]
```

I hope I believe given major changes both in tf2 and (TF-based) huggingface transformers

**UPDATE**

Here is the entire code with a dummy dataset; the whole thing is also available on [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QT2uEp8LtFyKjBixszasRwU8ZYg159r5?usp=sharing)

load the libraries

```
import os

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from transformers import TFBertPreTrainedModel
from transformers import TFBertMainLayer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tqdm import tqdm
from transformers import BertTokenizer
import tensorflow as tf
```

make a dummy data

```
x_train = ['هان از وقتی که زفتم مدرسه',
 'معاویه برادر شمر',
 'وقتی که از پنجره سرشرو میاره بیرون دالی میکنه',
 'هر دو سحرند این کجا و آن کجا']

y_train = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

x_test, x_valid = x_train, x_train
y_test, y_valid = y_train, y_train
```

add the configs

```
# general config
MAX_LEN = 128
batch_size = 32
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = batch_size
VALID_BATCH_SIZE = batch_size
TEST_BATCH_SIZE = batch_size

EPOCHS = 3
EEVERY_EPOCH = 1000
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5
CLIP = 0.0
```

make the data huggingface friendly

```
MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH = 'HooshvareLab/bert-fa-base-uncased'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH)


MAX_LEN = 128
def tokenize_sentences(sentences, tokenizer, max_seq_len = 128):
    tokenized_sentences = []
    for sentence in tqdm(sentences):
        tokenized_sentence = tokenizer.encode(
                            sentence,                  # Sentence to encode.
                            add_special_tokens = True, # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
                            max_length = max_seq_len,  # Truncate all sentences.
                    )
        
        tokenized_sentences.append(tokenized_sentence)
    return tokenized_sentences

    def create_attention_masks(tokenized_and_padded_sentences):
        attention_masks = []
        for sentence in tokenized_and_padded_sentences:
            att_mask = [int(token_id > 0) for token_id in sentence]
            attention_masks.append(att_mask)
        return np.asarray(attention_masks)
    
    train_ids = tokenize_sentences(x_train, tokenizer, max_seq_len = 128)
    train_ids = pad_sequences(train_ids, maxlen=MAX_LEN, dtype="long", value=0, truncating="post", padding="post")
    train_masks = create_attention_masks(train_ids)
    
    valid_ids = tokenize_sentences(x_valid, tokenizer, max_seq_len = 128)
    valid_ids = pad_sequences(valid_ids, maxlen=MAX_LEN, dtype="long", value=0, truncating="post", padding="post")
    valid_masks = create_attention_masks(valid_ids)
    
    test_ids = tokenize_sentences(x_test, tokenizer, max_seq_len = 128)
    test_ids = pad_sequences(test_ids, maxlen=MAX_LEN, dtype="long", value=0, truncating="post", padding="post")
    test_masks = create_attention_masks(test_ids)
```

create the datasets

```
def create_dataset(ids, masks, labels):
     def gen():
         for i in range(len(ids)):
             yield (
                 {
                     "input_ids": ids[i],
                     "attention_mask": masks[i]
                 },
                 labels[i],
             )
     return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
         gen,
         ({"input_ids": tf.int32, "attention_mask": tf.int32}, tf.int64),
         (
             {
                 "input_ids": tf.TensorShape([None]),
                 "attention_mask": tf.TensorShape([None])
             },
             tf.TensorShape([None]),
         ),
     )

train_dataset = create_dataset(train_ids, train_masks, y_train)
valid_dataset = create_dataset(valid_ids, valid_masks, y_valid)
test_dataset = create_dataset(test_ids, test_masks, y_test)
```

that is how the data looks like

```
for item in train_dataset.take(1):
  print(item)
```

[image]

Approach 1

```
class TFBertForMultilabelClassification(TFBertPreTrainedModel):

    def __init__(self, config, *inputs, **kwargs):
        super(TFBertForMultilabelClassification, self).__init__(config, *inputs, **kwargs)
        self.num_labels = config.num_labels

        self.bert = TFBertMainLayer(config, name='bert')
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)
        self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(config.num_labels,
                                                kernel_initializer='random_normal', #get_initializer(config.initializer_range),
                                                name='classifier',
                                                activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        outputs = self.bert(inputs, **kwargs)

        pooled_output = outputs[1]

        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output, training=kwargs.get('training', False))
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

        outputs = (logits,) + outputs[2:]  # add hidden states and attention if they are here

        return outputs  # logits, (hidden_states), (attentions)

NUM_LABELS = len(y_train[0])

model = TFBertForMultilabelClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH, num_labels=NUM_LABELS)


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001,epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1)
# we do not have one-hot vectors, we can use sparce categorical cross entropy and accuracy
loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, validation_data=valid_dataset)
```

with an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-36-8aa1173bef76> in <module>()
      4 metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
      5 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 6 history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, validation_data=valid_dataset)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1145, in train_step
        if list(y_pred.keys())[0] == "loss":

    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

**Approach 2:**

```
MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH = 'HooshvareLab/bert-fa-base-uncased'
NUM_LABELS = 7

from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification, BertConfig
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH, 
    config=BertConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_OR_PATH, num_labels=NUM_LABELS, problem_type="multi_label_classification")
    )

loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=115, validation_data=valid_dataset, validation_steps=7)
```

and the error

```
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 1151, in train_step
      loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1863, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5203, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      labels=target, logits=output)
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [128,7] and labels shape [7]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_67923]
```

Comment: can you provide some data and all imports to reproduce your problem

Comment: @AloneTogether I am happy you are asking for it - sure - but the question is gonna be way longer - give me a few hours.

Comment: @AloneTogether here you are - also deposited the code on colab notebook